# How to define more general boundary conditions for ConvolutionLayer?

Tags: list-manipulation, neural-networks, boundary-conditions, convolution

In Mathematica 12, I only see the option to define `"PaddingSize"` for a `ConvolutionLayer` in order to get Dirichlet boundary conditions (i.e. padding with 0's outside of the input image). In order to obtain some other type of boundary conditions (say, for example, Neumann), my best idea so far is to wrap the layer in a `NetChain` and use a `NetEncoder[{"Function", ...}]` there to extend the input in whatever way I desire. However, this is cumbersome, probably inefficient and makes it hard to use such a layer inside more complicated models. Any ideas how to proceed better?

**Sample code:**

The following convolution essentially computes the derivative of its 1D input:

```
conv = ConvolutionLayer["Biases" -> None, "Weights" -> {{{-1, 0, 1}}}, "PaddingSize" -> 1]
```

However, we immediately see that the Dirichlet boundary conditions provided by `"PaddingSize" -> 1` introduce some noise at the beginning and ending of the output, since

```
dims = {1, 10};
input = ConstantArray[1, dims];
conv@input
```

produces `{{1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1.}}` instead of the more natural `{{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}` (corresponding to Neumann boundary conditions). To solve this, we define

```
netenc = NetEncoder[{"Function", {Join[{First@First@#}, Flatten@#, {Last@First@#}]} &, dims + {0, 2}}];
```

which first extends the input with the Neumann boundary conditions, and then

```
net = NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer["Biases" -> None, "Weights" -> {{{-1, 0, 1}}}]}, "Input" -> netenc];
```

to compute the derivative in the interior of the extended region (i.e. with no `"PaddingSize"`). Now `net@input` returns `{{0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}}` as desired... but is there a better way to do the same?

Comment: Just realized that for Neumann boundary conditions, a better approach would be to use a PaddingLayer, say

`net=NetChain[{PaddingLayer[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, Padding -> "Fixed"], ConvolutionLayer["Biases" -> None, "Weights" -> {{{-1, 0, 1}}}]}]`

However, the question still stands for more general boundary conditions...